# App Crash with qtxml

Tags: c++, xml, qt, qtxml

i'm coding an function that read informations from xml file using QtXmlStreamReader , ther'is xml file

```
<favorites>
  <server>
    <ip>127.0.0.1:7777</ip>
    <nickname></nickname>
    <password></password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <ip>127.1.1.1:7777</ip>
    <nickname>bdfjhd</nickname>
    <password></password>
  </server>
  <server>
    <ip>125.1.1.1:5445</ip>
    <nickname>fdkgfhfhf</nickname>
    <password></password>
  </server>
</favorites>
```

and my function :

```
QString FavFile::GetFavListServers()
{
    QFile file("favlist.xml");
    file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QXmlStreamReader stream(&file);

    QString Ip;
    QString Name;
    QString Pass;

    try
    {
        while(stream.readNext() && !stream.isEndDocument())
        {
            if(stream.name() == "server")
            {
                qDebug() << "server found";

                while(stream.readNext() && !stream.isEndElement())
                {
                    if(stream.name() == "ip")
                    {
                        Ip = stream.readElementText();
                    }
                    if(stream.name() == "nickname")
                    {
                        Name = stream.readElementText();
                    }
                    if(stream.name() == "password")
                    {
                        Pass = stream.readElementText();
                    }
                }
                qDebug() << "IP: " + Ip;
            }
        }
    }
    catch(QException &ex)
    {
        qDebug() << "Bug In try";
    }

    file.close();
}
```

output

> server found
>   "IP: 127.0.0.1:7777"
>   server found
>   "IP: 127.1.1.1:7777"
>   server found
>   "IP: 125.1.1.1:5445"

Le programme s'est terminé subitement. ----> Crash Message

The function return fine the value but it crash all time :$

debug :

The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating system.

> Signal name :  SIGSEGV Signal meaning :  Segmentation fault

Comment: Which line does the crash occur on?

Comment: i don't  know :/

Comment: Run the code in your debugger, it will output a stack trace that includes the line it crashed on.

Comment: the loop didn't stop :/